# Bash or Python script to check numbers

Tags: python

I have a file in this format:

```
W 10 45 50
X 23 49 80
Y 55 90 56
Z 90 65 78
```

I want to check if all numbers in every row is greater than 50, print something and if not all are greater than 50, print something else.
How can I do that?

Here is my code to do a piece of the job:

```py
with open('the_numbers', 'r') as server:
    print([all([True if int(column)>=50 else False for column in server.readline().split(' ')[1:]]) for row in range(4)])
```

This gives me the output `[False, False, True, True]`, but I want to print the first columns for each row and then if it is `False`, print `Fail` , or it is `True`, print `Pass`:

```
W: Fail
X: Fail
Y: Pass
Z: Pass
```

Answer (score 8):

You may consider this `awk` solution:

```sh
awk '{printf "%s: ", $1; for (i=2; i<=NF; ++i) if ($i < 50) {print "Fail"; next}; print "Pass"}' file

W: Fail
X: Fail
Y: Pass
Z: Pass
```

Answer (score 5):

There is no prize to be won for one-liners. But there is a price to be paid for bad readability ;)

```
with open('the_numbers', 'r') as server:
    for row in server:
        tokens = row.split()
        pas = all(int(column) >= 50 for column in tokens[1:])
        print(f"{tokens[0]}: {('fail', 'pass')[pas]}")
```

Answer (score 2):

In Python you can do this.

```
with open('the_numbers', 'r') as server:
    for i in server:
        line = i.split(' ')
        status = all([True if int(column) >= 50 else False for column in line[1:]])
        # You can also do this. Based on Tuan Chau's suggestion.
        #status = all([int(column) >= 50 for column in line[1:]])
        print(f"{line[0]}: {['Fail', 'Pass'][status]}")
```

```
Output:

W: Fail
X: Fail
Y: Pass
Z: Pass
```

Comment: `True if int(column) >= 50 else False ` ~ `int(column) >= 50`

Answer (score 2):

```
def main():
    index = 0
    data_list = []
    with open('data.txt', 'r') as server:
        lines = server.readlines()

        for line in lines:
            is_pass = True
            for item in line.replace('\n', '').split(' '):
                if item.isnumeric():
                    if int(item) < 50:
                        is_pass = False
                else:
                    letter = item

            if is_pass:
                data_list.append((letter, 'pass'))
            else:
                data_list.append((letter, 'fail'))

    for d in data_list:
        print(d)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This is my answer with Python.

Answer (score 2):

This can be solved succinctly by using [assignment packing](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-assignment-stmt) and a [conditional expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions):

```py
with open('the_numbers', 'r') as server:
    for line in server:
        name, *nums = line.split()
        print(name, "Pass" if all(int(num) >= 50 for num in nums) else "Fail")
```

This is functionally very close to what is done in the question, but uses Python's language features for terseness and efficiency:

- By using `for line in server` one automatically gets the `server.readline()` lazy reading, without having to know the line count up front.
- By using `name, *nums = line.split()` one can succinctly split the line into leading element (`name`) and sequence of items (`nums`) without using magic numbers.
- By using `... if all(...) else` one can directly map the check to the desired output words.

Answer (score 2):

Pandas offers an elegant way to reduce tables.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('test.txt', header=None, sep=" ", index_col=0)
for name, result in df.ge(50).all(axis=1).iteritems():
    print(f"{name}: {'Pass' if result else 'Fail'}")
```

The `read_csv` function will parse the table into a dataframe and convert columns that appear to be a standard type - in this case, columns 1, 2, and 3 become integers.

```
>>> df = pd.read_csv('test.txt', header=None, sep=" ", index_col=0)
>>> df
    1   2   3
0
W  10  45  50
X  23  49  80
Y  55  90  56
Z  90  65  78
```

The `ge` method does the `>=` comparison

```
>>> df.ge(50)
       1      2     3
0
W  False  False  True
X  False  False  True
Y   True   True  True
Z   True   True  True
```

and `all` will reduce either the rows (axis=0) or columne (axis=1) into a single true/false value

```
>>> df.ge(50).all(axis=1)
0
W    False
X    False
Y     True
Z     True
dtype: bool
```

After that, its just a question of iterating the index and reduced value for your print.

pandas is not part of the standard library and will need to be installed separately.